# Python Tkinter How to update a text widget in a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to update text in a scrolltext widget within a for loop. The print statement shows the updated text each time through the loop but the I don't see anything in the Tk window until the loop has completed. Then I see 
'('This is ', 4, ' times though the loop.')'. 
I never see 0 through 3 being displayed.

```
from   tkinter import *
from   tkinter import scrolledtext
import time

main = Tk()
main.title("test_loop")
main.geometry('750x625')
main.configure(background='ivory3')


def show_msg():
    global texw
    textw = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(main,width=40,height=25)
    textw.grid(column=0, row=1,sticky=N+S+E+W)
    textw.config(background="light grey", foreground="black",
             font='arial 20 bold', wrap='word', relief="sunken", bd=5)
    for i in range(5):
        txt = "This is ", i, " times though the loop."
        txt = str(txt)
        print(txt)
        textw.delete('1.0', END)  # Delete any old text on the screen
        textw.update()            # Clear the screen.
        textw.insert(END, txt)    # Write the new data to the screen
        time.sleep(5)

btn = Button(main, text = 'display_log', bg='light grey', width = 15, 
         font='arial 12', relief="raised",bd=5,command = show_msg)
btn = btn.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First lets clean up the code to be more PEP8 friendly and also change import so we are not importing `*`. By importing `*` you run the risk of overwriting imports and built in methods.

I would create your widget outside of your function and then replace your loop containing `sleep()` with a function that can call itself and uses `after()` as sleep will block your mainloop rendering your GUI useless and frozen until all the sleeping has completed. `after()` is used to avoid this problem.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('test_loop')
root.geometry('750x625')
root.configure(background='ivory3')
textw = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=40, height=25)
textw.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='nsew')
textw.config(background='light grey', foreground='black', font='arial 20 bold', wrap='word', relief='sunken', bd=5)


def show_msg(count=None):
    if count is not None:
        if count <= 5:
            txt = 'This is {} times though the loop.'.format(count)
            textw.delete('1.0', 'end')
            textw.insert('end', txt)
            count += 1
            root.after(2000, lambda: show_msg(count))
    else:
        show_msg(1)


tk.Button(root, text='display_log', bg='light grey', width=15, font='arial 12', relief='raised', bd=5,
          command=show_msg).grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

If you want to keep all your logs on the screen (assuming you want to as normally logs should all be kept) I would remove the delete command and then add a `\n` to the text so each log is on a new line.

Simply edit the function like this:

```
def show_msg(count=None):
    if count is not None:
        if count <= 5:
            txt = 'This is {} times though the loop.\n'.format(count)
            # textw.delete('1.0', 'end')
            textw.insert('end', txt)
            count += 1
            root.after(2000, lambda: show_msg(count))
    else:
        show_msg(1)
```

Results:

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your window is not getting updated until the loop is running. To avoid it 'freezing', you should update it periodically. Do something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
do_your_init()
tk = Tk()
do_your_preparation()
for x in range(n):
    do_your_update()
    tk.update()
```

Hope that's helpful! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are sleeping after inserting the text, and then deleting the text before the next time you call `update`. The call to `update` needs to happen after inserting the text, not before.